# data in objdata[i]["Id"] store in separate array jquery json can is strore arr[i]=objdata[i]["Id"] like this?

Tags: jquery

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "train8.aspx/fetchemp",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                    var len = objdata.length;

                    $("#tbody1").empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var tr = "<tr>";
                        var td6 = "<td class='rownum' hidden>" + i + "</td>";
                        var td1 = "<td class='Id'hidden>" + objdata[i]["Id"] + "</td>";
                        var td2 = "<td class='name'>" + objdata[i]["name"] + "</td>";
                        var td3 = "<td class='gender'>" + objdata[i]["gender"] + "</td>";
                        var td4 = "<td class='pincode'>" + objdata[i]["pincode"] + "</td>";
                        var td5 = "<td class='City'>" + objdata[i]["City"] + "</td>";
                        var td7 = "<td class='btn'><button type='button' class='delete' id=" + i + ">delete</button></td></tr>";
                        $("#tbody1").append(tr + td6 + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5 + td7);



                    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome - your question is very unclear. Please edit it and make it readable and clear.

Comment: actually i am trying to save value in objdata[i]["Id"] in seprate array for example arr[i]=objdata[i]["Id"]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365820/convert-data-from-received-json-format-to-jvectormap-format/41366276#41366276

Comment: `var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);` you don't need this one.`datatype` option is already doing that for you.